# Mule ESB: Retrieving email messages from Gmail using IMAP connector

Tags: gmail, imap, mule, gmail-imap

I am new to Mule and im trying to create a Mule configuration that pulls sent emails from a GMail account via imap and pushes them to a php script that processes and stores them in a custom CRM that i've built.
For starters, i'm just trying to get the inbox emails dumped into a text files and i plan to work from there.

As new messages are received by the mailbox, Mule should pick up the new messages and process them automatically.

The Mule config looks like this so far:

```
<imaps:connector name="IMAP" mailboxFolder="INBOX" validateConnections="false" doc:name="IMAP" />
<flow name="flows1Flow1" doc:name="flows1Flow1">
    <imaps:inbound-endpoint host="imap.gmail.com" port="993" user="[[username]]%40gmail.com" password="[[password]]" connector-ref="IMAP" doc:name="IMAP"/>
   <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\mailflow" outputPattern="msg_#[function:date].txt" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

The program runs and gets to this point:

```
    INFO  2012-01-12 13:51:06,606 [main] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext: 
    **********************************************************************
    * Application: mailflow                                     *
    * OS encoding: Cp1252, Mule encoding: UTF-8                          *
    *                                                                    *
    * Agents Running:                                                    *
    *   JMX Agent                                                        *
    **********************************************************************
    INFO  2012-01-12 13:51:06,606 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: 
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + Started app 'mailflow'                          +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And then just sits there indefinitely, doing nothing?!

There is documentation suggesting that because i'm using IMAPS i need to add a TLS client and TLS key store to the imaps connector. I'm not sure what these are or how to use them though and the documentation is highly specialized and hard to understand.
I'm also not sure that that's what the problem is in the first place as the app doesn't crash at any point.

Has anyone had success creating an imap flow with GMail? 
Please Help?!

Answer (score 1):

Just create the connector like this:

```
<imaps:connector name="IMAP">
   <imaps:tls-client/>
   <imaps:tls-trust-store/>
</imaps:connector>
```

And that should do the trick.
Also, I'd remove the "@gmail" from the user's definition, since it's not necessary.

Bye!

German

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear: the tls-client and tls-trust-store elements both require a path attribute and a storePassword. like this:
`<imaps:tls-client path="" storePassword=""  />`
`<imaps:tls-trust-store storePassword="" path=""  />`
What is the path meant to point to and what/where is the password for/from? Is it my public key? or do i make it up?? its really not clear.

Comment: Hi, AFAIK you don't need to declare the path for the tls-client and trust-store. By declaring it as I showed you it will use the default keystores of your JVM. Give it a try as it is and let us know the results :)

Comment: Tx for your reply. I have been running the app without the client and trust store and it seems to run fine (ie. it doesn't crash) but it still just sits there.. it should be monitoring and pulling messages in from the mailbox, but it just sits there, with no activity..

Answer (score 1):

just put in a * and you wont see the error and will still work fine.

```
    <imaps:tls-client path="*" storePassword="*"/>
    <imaps:tls-trust-store path="*" storePassword="*"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `imap:connector` and `imap:inbound-endpoint` to `imaps:connector` and `imaps:inbound-endpoint`.

It is working fine for me. I have the same issued and now it is fixed with this little change.

Answer (score 0):

Only non-deleted and unread messages are dispatched as messages (RetrieveMessageReceiver.java:148 and 149)

```
if (!messages[i].getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.DELETED)
     && !messages[i].getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN))
```

If the folder is big, it will take some time (potentially even hours) to get to the point to process unread messages.

Answer (score 0):

[Settings for the IMAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKTMK.png)

Use the app password
https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
and finally use the correct path for the mail to be saved.