# Mule ESB 3.3 - Receiving IMAPS mail (Gmail)

Tags: ssl, gmail, imap, esb, mule

Anyone has a working example of reading mails from IMAP over SSL (IMAPS) from Gmail?

Some info I have gathered, but without any success:

- [Mule ESB: Retrieving email messages from Gmail using IMAP connector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8836530/496792)
- [IMAP Questions](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/imap_questions-1ib9zb)
- [Mule ESB IMAP questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190779/mule-esb-imap-questions?rq=1)
- and of course the infamous [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/IMAP+Endpoint+Reference)

The thing just sits there doing nothing.

Here is my flow:

```
<mule>
<imaps:connector
        name="imapsConnector"
        checkFrequency="5000"
        backupEnabled="true"
        mailboxFolder="INBOX"
        deleteReadMessages="false"
        doc:name="IMAP">
        <imaps:tls-client />
        <imaps:tls-trust-store />
    </imaps:connector>

    <expression-transformer
        name="returnAttachments"
        doc:name="Expression">
        <return-argument
            evaluator="attachments-list"
            expression="*.csv" />
    </expression-transformer>

    <flow
        name="GmailImapsFetch"
        doc:name="Flow1_IMAP_fetch">
        <imaps:inbound-endpoint
            user="your_username%40gmail.com"
            password="your_password"
            host="imap.googlemail.com"
            port="993"
            transformer-refs="returnAttachments"
            disableTransportTransformer="true"
            doc:name="IMAP"
            connector-ref="imapsConnector"
            responseTimeout="10000" />
        <!-- <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter" /> -->
        <logger message="#[payload]" />
        <file:outbound-endpoint
            path="/tmp/gmail-#[function:datestamp].dat"
            doc:name="File">
            <expression-transformer>
                <return-argument
                    expression="payload.inputStream"
                    evaluator="groovy" />
            </expression-transformer>
        </file:outbound-endpoint>

    </flow>
</mule>
```

Mule Studio (1.3.2) complains that the XML is malformed (it doesn't like the expression-transformer thingie), but it doesn't complain at runtime.

Anyone has this running?

Thanks.

--

Log:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Starting app 'mulelab'                                   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Applying lifecycle phase: org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextStartPhase@14b03ea for registry: DefaultRegistryBroker
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager@63edf84f
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Starting ResourceManager
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Restore retrieved 0 objects
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Restore retrieved 0 objects
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Restore retrieved 0 objects
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Started ResourceManager
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: FileConnector
. . .   
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: ImapsConnector
{
  name=imapsConnector
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=4bb4df9c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=false
  supportedProtocols=[imaps]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Connecting: ImapsConnector
{
  name=imapsConnector
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=4bb4df9c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=false
  supportedProtocols=[imaps]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Connected: ImapsConnector
{
  name=imapsConnector
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=4bb4df9c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[imaps]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Starting: ImapsConnector
{
  name=imapsConnector
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=4bb4df9c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[imaps]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Starting connector: imapsConnector
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Successfully connected to ImapsConnector
{
  name=imapsConnector
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=4bb4df9c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=false
  supportedProtocols=[imaps]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyWebappServerAgent@26945b95
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent@320f6398
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: SedaModel{_muleSystemModel}
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Starting model: _muleSystemModel
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: Flow{GmailImapsFetch}
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Starting flow: GmailImapsFetch
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Starting service: GmailImapsFetch.stage1
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Registering listener: GmailImapsFetch on endpointUri: imaps://your_username%40gmail.com:****@imap.googlemail.com:993
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Loading default inbound transformer: org.mule.transport.email.transformers.EmailMessageToString
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Setting transformer name to: EmailMessageToString#1868577756
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Initialising: 'null'. Object is: RetrieveMessageReceiver
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Connecting: RetrieveMessageReceiver{this=22fe135d, receiverKey=your_username@gmail.com, endpoint=imaps://your_username%40gmail.com:****@imap.googlemail.com:993}
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Connecting clusterizable message receiver
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] No Authenticator set on connector: imapsConnector; using default.
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Defaulting mule.email.imaps trust store to client Key Store
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] MuleSession local properties =============
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.imaps.ssl: true
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.debug: true
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.imaps.socketFactory.class: org.mule.transport.email.ImapsSocketFactory
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback: false
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.imap.host: imap.googlemail.com
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.imap.auth: true
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.imap.socketFactory.port: 993
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mail.imap.rsetbeforequit: true
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] skipped 0
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] System global properties =============
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.home: /home/pakmans/workspace/.mule
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.encoding: UTF-8
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] skipped 57
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Creating mail session: host = imap.googlemail.com, port = 993, user = your_username@gmail.com, pass = ********
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] creating: true; mule.email.imaps
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] creating factory
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Using org.mule.api.security.provider.SunSecurityProviderInfo
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.email.imaps.ssl.trustStore -> null
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.email.imaps.ssl.trustStoreType -> jks
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.email.imaps.ssl.trustStorePassword -> null
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.email.imaps.ssl.trustManagerAlgorithm -> SunX509
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.email.imaps.ssl.keyStore -> .keystore
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Unable to load resource from the file system: /home/pakmans/workspace/mulelab/.keystore
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Unable to load resource .keystore from the classpath
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] Normalised keyStore path to: null
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.email.imaps.ssl.keyStoreType -> jks
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] mule.email.imaps.ssl.keyStorePassword -> null
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [DEBUG] initialising: anon true
[23-01-13 11:07:01] [ INFO] Defaulting mule.email.imaps trust store to client Key Store
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Connected: imaps://your_username%40gmail.com:****@imap.googlemail.com:993
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] Starting: 'null'. Object is: RetrieveMessageReceiver
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] Starting clusterizable message receiver
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] RetrieveMessageReceiver@22fe135d scheduled ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@6fa37fac with 5000 MILLISECONDS polling frequency
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: DefaultInboundEndpoint{endpointUri=imaps://your_username%40gmail.com:<password>@imap.googlemail.com, connector=ImapsConnector
{
  name=imapsConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=4bb4df9c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[imaps]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.imaps.your_username.gmail.com', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] lifecycle phase: start for object: org.mule.DefaultMuleContext@6a9effe0
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] Reload interval: 3000
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wrapper-manager' is defined
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] registering key/object wrapper-manager/org.mule.module.management.agent.WrapperManagerAgent@4c825cf3
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] applying processors
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] applying lifecycle to object: org.mule.module.management.agent.WrapperManagerAgent@4c825cf3
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] This JVM hasn't been launched by the wrapper, the agent will not run.
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Registering statistics with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Statistics,name=AllStatistics
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Registering mule with name: Mule.mulelab:name=MuleContext
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Registering configuration with name: Mule.mulelab:name=Configuration
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Registering model with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Model,name="_muleSystemModel(seda)"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Registering service with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Flow,name="GmailImapsFetch"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'endpoint.imaps.your_username.gmail.com' is defined
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] Attempting to register service with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Endpoint,service="GmailImapsFetch",connector=imapsConnector,name="endpoint.imaps.your_username.gmail.com"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] Registered Endpoint Service with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Endpoint,service="GmailImapsFetch",connector=imapsConnector,name="endpoint.imaps.your_username.gmail.com"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'connector.file.mule.default.1' is defined
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Attempting to register service with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Connector,name="connector.file.mule.default.1"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] Registered Connector Service with name Mule.mulelab:type=Connector,name="connector.file.mule.default.1"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'imapsConnector.1' is defined
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Attempting to register service with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Connector,name="imapsConnector.1"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] Registered Connector Service with name Mule.mulelab:type=Connector,name="imapsConnector.1"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [DEBUG] Registering application statistics with name: Mule.mulelab:type=Application,name="application totals"
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] 
**********************************************************************
* Application: mulelab                                               *
* OS encoding: UTF-8, Mule encoding: UTF-8                           *
*                                                                    *
* Agents Running:                                                    *
*   JMX Agent                                                        *
**********************************************************************
[23-01-13 11:07:03] [ INFO] 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'mulelab'                                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: If you run with the logs at DEBUG level, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to see if this line in the receiver `logger.debug("ignoring exception: " + e.getMessage());` was called and it's not. The only option to learn more about the issue that I can think of is to step debug in `org.mule.transport.email.RetrieveMessageReceiver.poll()`. I don't have a spare GMail account so I can't do it myself, sorry.

Comment: I have debugged your suggested class, and I can see that it actually does connect and it actually retreives 7 messages (why 7? there are more than 7) but it keeps cycling those 7 messages. Those 7 messages by the way, are aleady read so it doesn't do anything.  If i mark it as unread y can see that it continues the flow.  Any ideas why it only read only 7 (continuosly)? Is it necessary to fetch all mail and check if it is already read localy instead of asking for only the unread mails?  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @pakman, did you ever get this working?  I have a similar setup, and I keep getting nothing happening.

Comment: @Don01001100 Yes, it was a language related issue... see my comment in David's answer.

Comment: Thanks @pakman.  I wasn't sure if that worked because the answer wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to risk an answer :$

According to the [IMAP's connector doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/IMAP+Transport+Reference#IMAPTransportReference-Connectors), it seems your config misses an attribute that is recommended with GMail:

> **moveToFolder**
>   The remote folder to move mail to once it has been read.
>   It is recommended that 'deleteReadMessages' is set to false when this
>   is used. This is very useful when working with public email services
>   such as GMail where marking messages for deletion doesn't work.
>   Instead set the @moveToFolder=[GMail]/Trash.

Can you give it a try?

(Edited: [Gmail] has to be surrounded by brackets)

Comment: I did try that but didn't work at first... after reading your answer I tried some more and it turns out it didn't work because my gmail account (actually a business account, not plain gmail) is in spanish so I had to use: moveToFolder=[Gmail]/Papelera  I still have the problem that if there are read messages in inbox, mule will cycle forever in the oldes 7 never getting to the unread ones.