# MULE ESB 3.4 IMAP Mail Proplem

Tags: ssl, imap, mule, esb

I'm Trying to Consume Messages From My Email Account and Transform it to Text Files

this is my Code

```
     <imaps:connector name="imapsConnector" backupEnabled="true" backupFolder="backup" checkFrequency="90000"deleteReadMessages="false" mailboxFolder="INBOX" moveToFolder="Processed"/> 
     <flow name="imapsFlow1" doc:name="imapsFlow1">
          <imaps:inbound-endpoint host="imap.gmail.com" port="993" user="mymail%40gmail" password="password" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="imapsConnector" doc:name="IMAP"/>
          <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/dev-5/Documents/IMAP" outputPattern="msg_#[function:date].txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
```

I have 2 Proplems
1- I can read from email one time and when i run the program again it doesn't read messages even i sent new messages to my mail
2- It reads only 7 mails as in the question 
[Mule ESB 3.3 - Receiving IMAPS mail (Gmail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484298/mule-esb-3-3-receiving-imaps-mail-gmail)

Answer (score 1):

It appears if there are more than 7 seen messages in the folder that you are reading from, it will not process anything until these messages are moved out of the folder.
So try copying the mails to another folder using moveToFolder="abc" in connector or try deleting read messages using deleteReadMessages="true" in connector.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens on 3.6.2 as well. Mulesoft has logged an internal ticket for this. Moving processed emails into a different folder is a workaround until the proper fix is provided.

Update: The fix will be included in 3.7.1, 3.6.3, 3.5.4 and 3.4.5 releases.
Until then, you can request for a hot fix if your are on a paid subscription.

Upd: The public ticket id for the issue is MULE-8776.